# Hindi font display through LWUIT

Tags: fonts, lwuit-resource-editor

I created **Hindi font resource**  (Mangal face) through LWUIT.

I have developed a small application which displays Hindi font on two components, Label and Text area. (Both components are LWUIT components)

It displays properly in Text Area **but not in Label**.

It displays as letters separate and Matras separate, not as combined. (ex: क + । = का ).

Please give suggestions to my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in your font file as well, what you can do is use system fonts for your application if using mangal font is not a compulsion. Can you share your font file so that i can dig deeper??